# MYSQL count based off of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

Sorry for asking this, but I haven't found an answer to what I'm trying to do anywhere!

Basically, I have a database with two tables. Below or two examples I'll use:

Table 1:

```
Process ID  Date
---------- -----------
         1  2008/08/21
         2  2008/08/23
         3  2008/08/21
```

Table 2:

```
Process ID Qty
---------- ---
         1   1
         2   4
         3   6
```

Basically, I was to do something in PHP where I will select table 1, and find all processes that occur today (in this example I'll say the 21st of August). I then want to take those process ids, and match them in Table two and give a count of their quantities.

The end result I'm trying to figure out in this example is how do I get the output to be "7" by using PHP to select the processes that happened today in one table, then add up the corresponding process quantities in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(t2.qty)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid
WHERE t1.date = '2008/08/21'
```

Comment: You are amazing! That was exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for saving me hours.